# Should the "conflict" tag stick around?

Tags: discussion, tags

<s>[conflict](/questions/tagged/conflict) and [conflicts](/questions/tagged/conflicts) are being used the same way and should be synonymized and/or merged (preferably in the direction of the latter).</s> [conflicts](/questions/tagged/conflicts) has been merged into [conflict](/questions/tagged/conflict).  Thanks Robert.

---

[conflict](/questions/tagged/conflict) is being used for a few unrelated things:

1. Conflicts in source control
2. Conflicts with binaries/libraries (version mismatches, etc.)
3. Other conflicts in general
4. When the word "conflict" appears in code (e.g., LINQ's "ConflictMode", which relates to case #3 as well)

If this tag stick around, I think we need to settle on one definition and clean it up.

The other solution is to kill it and have more specific tags, e.g., [source-control-conflict](/questions/tagged/source-control-conflict) or [binary-incompatibility](/questions/tagged/binary-incompatibility).  Unfortunately I can't think up better tags (less awkward and easier to find while still being specific enough), so I'm not sure what the best course of action is here.

Comment: [conflict] looks like it is the master tag.